# Problems when using load function of Tensorflow Datasets

Tags: python

I am trying to load a Dataset from Tensorflow Datasets API, but it doesn't work.

The error is the following: 
   AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat' has no attribute 'v1'

I have no idea what the cause could be, anyone any ideas?
Tensorflow Version: 2.0.0-beta1
tfds Version: 2.0.0

Thanks in advance

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

dataset, metadata = tfds.load(name="cycle_gan/horse2zebra", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

Comment: Include versions of `tensorflow` and `tfds`, there are major differences between those.

Comment: Try updating your `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-datasets` to the latest version. This requires upgrading pip: `python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks, upgrading to tensorflow 2.1 seems to solve the problem